# Overlapping equivalent of Array#slice

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given this Ruby array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What is the easiest way to iterate it like this?

```
[[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,5]]
```

Or this?

```
[[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]]
```

Comment: This is one of the problems from exercism.io lol

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`each_cons` ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)) does this. You just pass it the size of the chunks you want and it will yield them to the block you pass.

If you actually want the arrays, then you can of course chain this with `to_a`, for example

```
(1..5).each_cons(3).to_a
```

Comment: This is excellent, I didn't know about the #each_cons method... Got to love Ruby!

Comment: Right on! I thought i remembered i had seen it somewhere inside stdlib... 8P

Comment: @hwatkins, Ruby's Enumerable is chock-full of goodness like this.